# Why is there insulation in the common wall between housing units?

Tags: walls, insulation, cables

I need to run electrical and network cables (cat6) from the third floor of my house down to the basement where there are different breakers and different computers.

So I did a relative measurement in both places that I hope lines up so I can drop the cables down.

From the basement there is a hole that looks like this going up inside the wall in the house:

[image: Image looking from my basement up the hole]

Upstairs I tried drilling a hole in the wall (and it's an inner wall between my and the neighbors side of the house) but oddly I found a sheet of insulation blocking my way (see below):

[image: Peekaboo! Insulation says hello! Through the hole I drilled in the middle wall]

Since the insulation is in an interior wall (see below),

[image]

I don't know why it is there.  What I do know is that when my neighbor hangs things on the wall on the interior wall the screws come through the other side, so I was very careful not to drill through her side of the wall, which is how I found the insulation.

I don't know why it's there, but it's preventing me from getting my cables run.

Does anyone know why it's there or what I can do about it?

Comment: Note that if you're in a duplex or apartment building, that wall needs to be *fire rated* under current building codes...so I'd be thinking about a different route for your cabling, as well as repairing the drywall where you already made the hole

Comment: Insulation is commonly used for sound dampening between adjoining units. Is that the extent of your question?

Comment: Think about if you want your unit to be cool and your neighbor wants theirs to feel like a sauna.

Comment: I own half of the house.  Technically I'm in the attic, it's just my side is finished, I don't believe her's is as I can see through the boards to the other side and her side of the attic looks like an attic, my side looks like a room.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That's no drywall, that's pretty thick wood.

Comment: @leeand00 -- well, the paneling where you already made the hole, but that's odd that the party wall between you and your neighbors would be finished with wood sheathing/paneling, unless you're talking about the lath which plaster was applied over...?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It’s an old house I think it was built in the 50s.  There’s no drywall in this place at all.  That’s why I still have so many pictures on the floor.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel what is lath?

Comment: @leeand00 -- plaster is applied over either wood strips, metal mesh, or a thin form of gypsum board, any of those things could be called "lath" but it's usually reserved for the wood strips or metal mesh

Comment: @leeand00 search for "plaster and lath" to understand how your walls were built. The inside of your walls looks exactly like the inside of mine... It's got advantages and drawbacks for the renovator.

Comment: I added a picture of the wall from afar if it helps.

Comment: Your "wide" pic looks like that used to be an exterior wall, then they added on. Of course, someone could have just used siding as an interior wall finish, there's nothing wrong with that. This would account for the "very thick wood" you noted above. TBH, plaster & lathe makes hanging pictures dead easy: "You want it here?" _Drives screw, job done._ No worries about finding a stud or using a molly/anchor. As noted, I've done that in my house for years with P&L walls. Finally - I like your network rack!

Comment: @FreeMan I believe they used the siding as an interior wall finish.  Yes, pegboard is a wondrous thing isn't it? :)  I'm still a little new to proper organized cabling, but I did my best in haste.

Comment: Consider it a beta test. :)

Answer (score 4):

The first 3 comments are all correct answers.

Comment #1 by ThreePhaseEel regarding a code required fire wall is correct, but it’s for fire rated draftstops between living units.

Comment #2 by Isherwood regarding sound control is also correct. The code requires a minimum STC rating between units and insulation can fill the voids and help with that requirement.

Comment #3 by whatsisname regarding a thermal barrier is also a code requirement. The requirement is for the envelope around a unit...there is no exception for common party walls.

Do not remove the insulation just to extend some cables from your attic to the other floors.