# Curtan rod pulled spacle out of wall?

Tags: walls, hole, hole-repair

I'm not sure what type of walls I have in the first floor of my house, but it looks as though someone   tried to Spackle a hole     and the curtain rod bracket has just fallen out, since the bracket was attached to the Spackle.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Or is it just going to go on with me applying Spackle and it falling out of the wall until there's a hole big enough that I should just add another door?

[image]

Comment: Spackle  it is the way to repair the hole,  NOT re-installing the bracket in the repaired  hole is the way to avoid it becoming a doorway.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell but I think you have lath and plaster.

If that is the case then you break away the loose plaster exposing the lath (thin wood boards).  Once you have the lath exposed you use [concrete fill](https://www.usg.com/content/usgcom/en_CA_east/products/walls/drywall/joint-compound/concrete-finishing-compounds/synko-concrete-fill.html) ( a fiberglass re-inforced setting compound ) to get to the same vertical plane as the wall.

Typically you'll have a rough area at this point and you apply a finish coat of setting compound.  I'd go with a 30 minute setting compound.  Once the setting compound dries, you sand and then paint.

Now that the area is finished again you can use toggle bolts to hold the curtain rod bracket in place (assuming the spot that the bracket needs to sit doesn't have framing behind it).

Comment: Does this look like lath?  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/210597/why-is-there-insulation-in-the-common-wall-between-housing-units

Comment: yes the plaster has formed the key structure locking it into the lath.